# how do I do global substitutions?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

In vsvim for visual studio, I can highlight a selection and type `:s/hello/world/g` to get all occurrences of `hello` inside my selection with `world` but this isn't working in VsCode Vim, is this a feature not in this version of vim or is the special key sequence different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After selecting some lines and pressing `:` you should find that the Vim command line has been defaulted to `'<,'>` - this is a Vim range that refers to the selected lines. You need to keep this range as part of the command and type the `s/...` afterwards i.e.

```
:'<,'>s/hello/world/g
```

or if you just want to replace all occurrences across the whole file you can skip highlighting the lines and use the `%` range which indicates the whole file:

```
:%s/hello/world/g
```

If curious, you can [learn more about some of the other ranges that can be used.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges)

Comment: `So it looks like VS Code Vim is being slightly truer to the behaviour of Vim itself (although in Vim, if you do have a selection the '<,'> will be entered automatically for you.)` I'm not sure about that. I just tried it in VsVim, and the range is definitely inserted. I suppose it's possible I'm using a different version than the OP though.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem have just made sure everything is up to date here and you're right - the same happens for me now. Will update the answer to reflect this. The `'<,'>` _is_ selected after pressing `:` so it's also possible the OP is unintentionally replacing/overwriting it.

Comment: that's exactly what's happening. in vs code's vim, the `'<,'>` is being auto selected, so typing s overwrites it. whereas in vsvim the range deal is not selected, so typing s just adds to the command you are building. thanks.